# How to overclock Intel E2140 CPU?

Tags: windows, overclocking

I'd like to overclock my CPU as much as I can. If anyone can show me a good tutorial or tell me step by step how to do it I'd appreciate it. I've never done this..

Here is my config:
**Operating System** :  Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1.7600
**CPU Type** :  DualCore Intel Pentium E2140, 1600 MHz (8 x 200)
**Motherboard Name** :  ASRock 775i945GZ (3 PCI, 1 AGI Express, 1 HDMR, 2 DDR2 DIMM, Audio, Video, LAN)
**System Memory** :  1015 MB (DDR2-667 DDR2 SDRAM)
   DIMM3: Kingston   1 GB DDR2-667 DDR2 SDRAM (5-5-5-15 @ 333 MHz) (4-4-4-12 @ 266 MHz) (3-3-3-9 @ 200 MHz)
**BIOS Type** :  AMI (05/28/07)
**Video Adapter**  : Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family (256 MB)
**3D Accelerator**  : Intel GMA 950

If you need anything else add a comment.

Thanks

Comment: The video card question should probably be a separate question.

Comment: Many overclocking questions have been asked also: Please see: http://superuser.com/questions/17513/what-steps-do-you-take-when-overclocking

Comment: good info here: http://superuser.com/questions/25941/what-is-overclocking-the-system

Comment: You want to be careful, or your going to be asking questions like these:  http://superuser.com/questions/36500/memory-fsb-overclocking-and-heat-issues   and   http://superuser.com/questions/35200/overclocking-intel-e2180-problems

Comment: Under motherboard you have AGI Express listed as a slot. This doesn't exits. I think you mean PCI Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... if this is your first time my best advise would be `don't do it!` :)
Doing it in the presence of someone who already knows the secrets of the trade would ensure any mistakes didn't turn catastrophic (as in, `Oops! I just fried my processor`)

But ok. Fair enough. No one really learns without getting their hands dirty. So here's my effort at this question:

**The One Rule. The Mother Rule. Thou shalt not ignore this rule!**

> Always overclock by small increases.

Start Here:
[Intel Overclocking Guide](http://www.overclock.net/intel-cpus/1567-intel-overclocking-guide.html) by NoAffinity

With that covered:
[A nice starters tutorial](http://www.hexus.net/content/item.php?item=9808), at Hexus
[A in-depth Intel Core 2 article](http://www.tweaktown.com/articles/944/overclocking_intel_core_2_processors_how_far_will_they_go/index.html), at tweaktown

Finally:
[Intel Pentium E2140 specific information](http://xtreview.com/review197.htm), at xtreview
[Some Intel Pentium E2140 overclock results](http://www.ocforums.com/showthread.php?t=513496), on the OCForums

Comment: Thank you. I'll start and read everything and I'm thinking at buying a better cooler for the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you've never overclocked before, I'm forced to first caution you.

You *can* ruin hardware from overclocking.

However, overclocking is all about pushing your CPU clock and multiplier (if unlocked) as high as it will go while remaining stable and at low temperatures.

Honestly, you won't get much out of it and it will reduce the life of your CPU.

[Here is a much more in depth how to](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1804).

Comment: Not true about the performance gains. The Pentium Dual Core line (which his chip is) can reach 3GHz quite often. For most home-office users that are just using Word, this doesn't do much. But if you're doing video encoding or gaming it can provide a huge benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an older system that you would like to push to its max potential.  Without spending any money on upgraded cooling(heatsink, fans, etc.), I do not think you will see as much benefit as you would like to see.

Putting the hardware damage risk aside,  The hardware you listed is average quality and that will limit your overclocking abilities.  It can be much more than just pushing your CPU a few more cycles.

Many of the answers you will recieve on this question will be similar to all the questions I commented about above.